# Using Generics for return type parameter Java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a method that will return a generic type parameter.

I have a class VehicleOrder that extends the abstract class Order.
In class Order, I created an abstract method receiveHiredObject. This method will not receive any parameter and will return a generic.

```
public abstract class Order implements Orderable {

private Date date;
private Customer customer;

public abstract <T> T receiveHiredObject();
```

I implemented this method in the class VehicleOrder and I set it up to return the class parameter vehicle.

```
public class VehicleOrder extends Order {

private Vehicle vehicle;

public VehicleOrder(final Date date, final Customer customer, final Vehicle vehicle) {
    super(date, customer);
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Vehicle receiveHiredObject() {
    return vehicle;
}
```

The problem is that when I'm instantiating a new VehilceOrder of the type Order and, am using the method receiveHiredObject, this method is returning me an Object and I have available only the method toString.

```
Order a = new VehicleOrder();
a.receiveHiredObject();
```

I want that in the future to use the same method for other types of objects like HotelOrder.

What I'm doing wrong, why does the method receiveHiredObject is returning an Object instead of a VehicleOrder? How can I improve the method to return the right type?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you make the `Order` class generic, and have `VehicleOrder extends Order<Vehicle>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `receiveHiredObject` does "return the right type", if you tell it what type to return.

```
Order order = new VehicleOrder();
Vehicle v = order.receiveHiredObject();
```

It returns `Object` because without you specifying a type, the type parameter `T` gets inferred to be `Object`, because `T` is only bounded by `Object`.

***However***, your method is not safe at all! You can do silly things like:

```
Order order = new VehicleOrder();
Hotel h = order.receiveHiredObject();
```

And this will compile, but crash when you run it.

This is because you declared `receiveHiredObject` to return a `T` - the generic parameter. This means that whatever `T` that the caller specifies - whether it is `Vehicle`, `Hotel`, or `Foo`, `receiveHiredObject` is declared to return that type of thing. Clearly, it doesn't do that. What it returns depends on the subclass used. The caller doesn't get to decide what it returns! When you implement `receiveHiredObject` in `VehicleOrder`, you received a warning because returning a `Vehicle` might not be the `T` that the caller expects and the runtime cannot check this for you, but you suppressed the warning.

So `receiveHiredObject` should not be generic at all. You can instead make `Order` generic:

```
// might have to change Orderable too, if receiveHiredObject comes from there
public abstract class Order<T> implements Orderable {

    private Date date;
    private Customer customer;

    public abstract T receiveHiredObject();
}

public class VehicleOrder extends Order<Vehicle> {
    // same code as before...
}
```

Now the caller can do:

```
Order<Vehicle> order = new VehicleOrder();
order.receiveHiredObject().someVehicleSpecificThing();
```

Now it is much safer - you won't be able to get hotels from a vehicle order.

Note that it is absolutely necessary to provide the type information of `Vehicle`. This is because what `order.receiveHiredObject` returns is determined by the runtime type of `order`, and the *compiler* has no way of knowing what that is. Think in the extreme case:

```
Order order = new Random().nextBoolean() ? new VehicleOrder() : new HotelOrder();
// what type should order.receiveHiredObject return here?
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the explication now it's all clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could move the generic type declaration to the class level for example:

```
public abstract class Order<T> implements Orderable {
    private Date date;
    private Customer customer;

    public abstract T receiveHiredObject();
}

public class VehicleOrder extends Order<Vehicle> {

    private Vehicle vehicle;

    public VehicleOrder(final Date date, final Customer customer, final Vehicle vehicle) {
        super(date, customer);
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Vehicle receiveHiredObject() {
         return vehicle;
    }
}
```

(Think syntax is correct)

Comment: Advantage: the SuppressWarnings can be dropped.